# Would anything happen if the Resurrection Stone was thrown into The Veil?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, magical-theory

I am wondering if anything would happen if someone were to throw the Resurrection Stone through The Veil  in the Department of Mysteries.

For example, after throwing the Resurrection Stone into The Veil, would the dead immediately start coming out of The Veil and continue to keep coming out? Moreover, would they be just spirits or would they have the bodies they had when they died?

Comment: There's no answer to your question, there's almost no canon about The Veil, nor what happens if you start throwing objects into it. I think this might be opinion based.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, "what if this happened" questions are unanswerable, unless it actually happened in a published work.

Comment: @Roberto, well, from what I read about the Veil, it is a gateway to the land of the dead.

Comment: @Spencer, it's known that the Resurrection Stone can bring the dead back to life, so if there are dead people/souls just on the other side of the Veil, then it's reasonable to assume that the Resurrection Stone may have an effect on the magical barrier between the living and the dead which is maintained by the Veil.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Nothing would happen. The stone must be turned three times to work.

The Resurrection Stone does not just randomly conjure shadows of those who had died. It first has to be turned three times, presumably while being held by a wizard intending to use its ability to bring forth these shadows. The only time it does so, Harry had first turned it in his hand three times with the intention of seeing his dead loved ones, and it only brought back people who Harry loved and would want to see - even once active it did not conjure any random dead wizards.

> “The black stone with its jagged crack running down the centre sat in the two halves of the Snitch. The Resurrection Stone had cracked down the vertical line representing the Elder Wand. The triangle and circle representing the Cloak and the stone were still discernible.
>
> And again, Harry understood, without having to think. It did not matter about bringing them back, for he was about to join them. He was not really fetching them: they were fetching him.
>
> He closed his eyes, and turned the stone over in his hand, three times.
>
> He knew it had happened, because he heard slight movements around him that suggested frail bodies shifting their footing on the earthy, twig-strewn ground that marked the outer edge of the Forest. He opened his eyes and looked around.
>
> They were neither ghost nor truly flesh, he could see that.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 34 (The Forest Again)*</sup></sub>

It clearly does not choose to conjure these shadows on its own, as Dumbledore tried to use it and was unsuccessful.

> “After another short pause, Harry said, ‘You tried to use the Resurrection Stone.’
>
> Dumbledore nodded.
>
> ‘When I discovered it, after all those years, buried in the abandoned home of the Gaunts, the Hallow I had craved most of all – though in my youth I had wanted it for very different reasons – I lost my head, Harry. I quite forgot that it was now a Horcrux, that the ring was sure to carry a curse. I picked it up, and I put it on, and for a second I imagined that I was about to see Ariana, and my mother, and my father, and to tell them how very, very sorry I was …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 35 (King’s Cross)*</sup></sub>

Additionally, the Gaunt family wore it as a ring for centuries.

> “For a moment, Harry thought Gaunt was making an obscene hand gesture, but then realised that he was showing Ogden the ugly, black-stoned ring he was wearing on his middle finger, waving it before Ogden’s eyes. ‘See this? See this? Know what it is? Know where it came from? Centuries it’s been in our family, that’s how far back we go, and pure-blood all the way! Know how much I’ve been offered for this, with the Peverell coat of arms engraved on the stone?” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 10 (The House of Gaunt)*</sup></sub>

Then Voldemort also wore it as a ring for a bit before turning it into a Horcrux.

> “And Voldemort never knew about the Hallows?’
>
> ‘I do not think so, because he did not recognise the Resurrection Stone he turned into a Horcrux.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 35 (King’s Cross)*</sup></sub>

The Veil is unlikely to be able to activate the Stone itself. Presumably, if the Resurrection Stone was simply thrown into the Veil, it would have no effect - it would be like throwing any other stone through the veil.

Comment: I didn't know about having to turn it three times for it to work. I was just wondering if the magic within the stone would somehow interfere with the magic in the Veil and there may be an adverse effect, such as the Veil losing its power to keep the dead from passing through it.

Comment: @user255577 Since the magic in the Resurrection Stone is dormant until it is turned three times, it seems most likely that the magic lying dormant within the Stone would have no effect on the veil.

Comment: I see your point and I agree with you.

Comment: What happens if the Stone is spinning in the air, turning over and over, *while* it goes through the Veil?! :-)

Comment: I think it would probably disappear. Sirius' physical form and clothes and everything disappeared as far as we know.

Comment: @Rand what if a shark and a gorilla were there too? :D

Comment: @Randal'Thor, that's very interesting, something might happen then.

Comment: As usual, a very well reasoned answer. I'm assuming the stone needs to be intentionally turned while being held or else it would conjure the dead every time you went on the rides at Alton Towers or Chessington.

Comment: @Valorum, who knows, maybe one of the dead in the land of the dead could pick up the stone and use it to resurrect himself, that is if he knew what it was and knew how to use it such as spirit of Dumbledore.

Comment: @Valorum Thanks a lot! :) That’s a great point about an intention to conjure the dead while holding the Stone being necessary as well, I’ve updated my answer to include the matter of intention more specifically.